# What is the difference between hdfs dfs -get & -getmerge command?

Tags: hdfs, export-to-csv

The reason why I am asking this question is I have noticed that while I was using -get command to get a hdfs dataframe (saved as csv) in one single csv in my local, I was not getting headers of the csv. However, using -getmerge I am getting one single csv file with the headers. So, now I am bit confused about what is the difference between the two?

Comment: I believe in both cases it completely depends on how the data is stored. If data stored in hdfs with header it you should be getting data with headers. May be you can try -getmerge on the single csv file and see if you get with header. At least -getmerge serves the only purpose of merging multiple part files into single file.

Comment: The data was stored as csv in hdfs with headers = True. That is why, I found it strange that with -get on a single partition I was getting no headers but with -getmerge I was getting the final csv with header.